# datesuffix format using spark or aws step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-step-functions

how i can get formatted date in json file in aws step functions

sample json file: this creates step function via internal CICD on aws 
datesuffix has "04-05-2022" format

```
Parameters:{
    "loads.$":$.loads",
    tasktimeOutseconds.$":"$.taskTimeOutSeconds",  
    "dateSuffix.$":"$.cluster.Payload.Datesuffix",
    },
    "Next"."Spark-submit-test"
    "Type":"Pass"
   },
--
--
--
--"Spark-submit-test":{
   "Resultpath:$.FeaturecomputeforEMR",
   "Parameters" :{
    "taskName":"Spark-submit-test",
      "Args":[
       {
         "Args1":"spark-submit"
       },
      { 
         "Args2":"--master"
      }
    --
    --
    --
    {
    args16.$":"States.Format('s3a://{{e_bucket_name}}/{}/test/',$.dateSuffix)"
    },
     {
    args17.$":"States.Format('s3a://{{e_bucket_name}}/{}/test2/',$.**dateSuffix2**)"
    },
```

datesuffix2 i want format as "20220405" because in s3://drdata/usa/20220405
any idea how i can format date in step functions json file , please suggest

or how can i read it from spark directly

```
s3 location cMerge="s3://drdata/usa/20220405/test.csv"
val formcdi=new simepleDateformat("YYYYMMdd")
val formatnew=formcdi.format(c.getTime()).toString;
val c=spark.read.option("delimeter",",").csv(config.CMerge).{$formatnew)
```

Comment: i just changed aws lambda  code ,variables dateformat %Y%M%d 
it worked

Answer (score 2):

Step Functions cannot natively transform strings.  Its list of [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) is very short.

Use a [Lambda Task State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-lambda.html) to manipulate the date string.